# Numba'fied function evaluates differently in for loop then pure Python one

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm using numba to speed up functions including many for loops. Than they are called in outside for loop.

One of the functions evaluates differently  to not jited one when called in loop.

The function:

```
def collison(u, v, f, feq, omega, w, cx, cy, n, m):
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, n):
            t1 = u[i,j]*u[i,j] + v[i,j]*v[i,j]
            for k in range(9):
                t2 = u[i,j]*cx[k] + v[i,j]*cy[k]
                feq[k,i,j] = rho[i,j]*w[k]*(1. + 3.*t2 + 4.5*t2**2 - 1.5*t1)
                f[k,i,j] = omega*feq[k, i, j] + (1. - omega)*f[k, i, j]
    return f
```

`u`, `v`  - ndarray n x m 
`f`, `feq` - ndarray 9 x n x m

I just add decorator: `@nb.jit(nopython=True)` before declaration

The loop:

```
for tstep in range(mstep):
    fk = collison(u, v, fw, feq, omega, w, cx, cy, n, m)
    fs = stream(fk, n, m)
    fw = wbrzeg(fs, n, m, u0)
    rho, u, v = rhouv(fw, rho, u, v, cx, cy, n, m)
```

Could it be that `fw` is not being updated when `collision` is called ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the jitted function `rho` is taken as constant at the moment Numba compiles the function. This is different from the non-jitted function that always considers the updated `rho`.

See [this entry](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/faq.html#numba-doesn-t-seem-to-care-when-i-modify-a-global-variable) in the Numba FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here, but in the tstep loop, fw should be changed by collision, but it's never actually USED until after it's changed again by wbrzeg (whatever that is). So, in your code, it doesn't actually MATTER if fw is being updated by collision...

It's possible that this is just a typeo in your example somewhere, but fixing that might help someone who actually understands your problem (ie not me)...